# SWIFT: How to fix cell highlighter and make the whole collection view scroll instead of the highlighter?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, tvos

I am building a **TVOS app** where I have this **collectionView**:
[image]
The **current cell** (The cell which has scrolled to), gets highlighted in Orange.
For example, here the user scrolls to the third cell:
[image]
**WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE:**
When the user scrolls to another cell, I want the **Orange square**, to remain in the **first cell**, and the **whole collection** to scroll to the left(or to the right if the user is scrolling in the opposite direction.
And I honestly have no idea how to achieve this, or what should I use exactly.
Should I embed the whole collection view inside of a scrollView?
Anyway, here's how implemented that collection view:

```
extension MoviesViewController2: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            print("first function collectionView detected")
            return items2.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:
            cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! movieCardCell
              cell.movieImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: items2[indexPath.item].imageURL))
            return cell
    }
    
    // Handle collectionViewItem selection
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didSelectItem\(indexPath)")
    }
    
    // Highlight the current cell
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        if let pindex  = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath, let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: pindex) {
            cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
            cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
            cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
        }
        
        if let index  = context.nextFocusedIndexPath, let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: index) {
            cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 8.0
            cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
            cell.contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
            cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
            cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
            cell.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: index, at: [.centeredHorizontally, .centeredVertically], animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can answer the question above, it'd be great. Also any tip or what I should use is most welcome.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question well. But I think just simple put another UIView with orange border color on the top of your scrollview, and it's done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you want the orange rectangle to remain always on the same place. When scrolling you can make it disappear and re-appear once the scrolling has stopped maybe but that's a detail.

So you could put a `UIView` with the same dimensions as a cell (since all seem to have the same height and width) and make it appear once the user has stopped scrolling.

Anyway I'm looking again at your question and I think I didn't understand your issue correctly, specifically this part `The current cell (The cell which has scrolled to), gets highlighted in Orange.` in combination with this `When the user scrolls to another cell, I want the Orange square, to remain in the first cell`

Comment: If you feel like the question helped you please accept it, otherwise please let us know how else we can help you

Answer (score 1):

The process might be as follows:

- Set your collectionView's size to single cell size. And align it to the left
- Make your collectionView's clipsToBounds property to false
- Make UICollectionView paging enabled.
- Place a rectangle view on top of your collectionView